# How can I make div width adapt to inner image's width:auto?

Tags: css

I'm using bootstrap-vue modal to display images and would like the image to never be longer than 80% viewport height (and image's width to be scaled proportionally). Problem is that with this approach `.modal-dialog`'s width doesn't always match image's width, inspite having `width: auto` on `.modal-dialog`.

It works when image is small (like in the snippet), but on larger screen image overflows `modal-dialog` (can be reproduced at codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MMBKYP)

[image]

```css
img {
  max-height: 80vh;
  width: auto;
}

.modal {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  position: fixed;
  text-align: left;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}

.modal-dialog {
  border: 3px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;

  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  text-align: left;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-md">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/41/Wac_nearside_3000.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I make `.modal-dialog` width always fit the image width?

Comment: what steps to reproduce the issue? it's working fine in the codepen

Comment: @TemaniAfif updated editor's layout on codepen so that preview is larger now

Comment: you are probably looking for `max-width:100%` on the image

Comment: @TemaniAfif but then it makes image to scale down to fit the div's `max-width`, I want it other way around: to adapt the div width to image

Comment: I've just found I can use `max-width:max-content` on the div and it seems to do the job but is it a good practice?

Comment: simply remove `max-width` and it will do the same .. `max-content` is not yet supported everywhere

Comment: @TemaniAfif since `max-width` is already set by `bootstrap-vue`, I can only overwrite (supersede) this property with another one and it works only with `max-content` or `fit-content` (setting `max-width` to: unset, none, inherit or initial extends div to 100% viewport width)

Comment: share your full code including bootstrap then. You are describing things we cannot see. Considering your question, the modal is set to `inline-block` so logically you don't need any max-width

Comment: If there is `max-width` in the stylesheet, simply reset it with `max-width:none;` in your own styles. And judging by your comments, you may have to override more properties to undo all of Bootstrap's effects.